# In R can you reference a value within a df$var command

Tags: r

I am processing a variable called buffer_regions from a frame called origframe, which is populated with values like POSTAL_DIST_AB, POSTAL_DIST_AC etc

**My dataframe (origframe)**

```
buffer_regions |
-------------- |
POSTAL_DIST_AB |
POSTAL_DIST_AC |
POSTAL_DIST_AD |
```

I am trying to use the following code to create a new frame (Z_output) with a derived column (called POSTAL_DIST) which is based on origframe$buffer_regions but by removing the string which region is set to ("POSTAL_DIST") and the subsequent underscore. I don't want to hard-code the term POSTAL_DIST anywhere other than when setting the value of region (`region <- "POSTAL_DIST"`) as this is at the top of a larger programme:

```
require(stringr)
region <- "POSTAL_DIST"
z_output$region <- str_replace_all(final_buffer_list$buffer_regions, region, "")
```

**Desire outcome**

```
buffer_regions | POSTAL_DIST
-------------- | -------------- 
POSTAL_DIST_AB | AB
POSTAL_DIST_AC | AC
POSTAL_DIST_AD | AD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `substring`

```
origframe$POSTAL_DIST <- substring(origframe$buffer_regions, 
                        nchar(origframe$buffer_regions)-1)
origframe$POSTAL_DIST
#[1] "AB" "AC" "AD"
```

Or with `sub`

```
sub(".*_", "", origframe$buffer_regions)
```

#### data

```
origframe <- structure(list(buffer_regions = c("POSTAL_DIST_AB", 
"POSTAL_DIST_AC", 
"POSTAL_DIST_AD")), .Names = "buffer_regions", class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. The first code line would work perfectly apart from the hard coded `origframe$POSTAL_DIST` is there not a way to reference my value to something like: `region <- "POSTAL_DIST"` `origframe$region <- substring(origframe$buffer_regions, nchar(str1)-1)
origframe$region`?

Comment: @JoelB You can do that in `sub` i.e. `sub(paste0(region, "_"), '', origframe$buffer_regions)`